# My new straight shower arm has no thread one end

Tags: plumbing, shower, valve

Just bought a new shower and the 500mm straight arm has no thread one end as it’s designed to cut to size. What connection do you use to connect it in the loft to the 15mm plastic pipe please?

Many thanks in advance.

Andy

Comment: Product link? Surely, it has its own slip coupling you shove the cut off in? What does it say in the instructions about tools and materials required that are not included?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to see how this place works and the appropriate way to say "thanks" and acknowledge answer(s) that help you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a compression fitting, shower arm to plastic pipe similar to the one shown below from Trading Depot. Pipe and shower arms can vary in diameter so your best bet would be to bring the arm and a piece of scrap pipe to your plumbing supply or home store to get a perfect match. It would be much easier to connect if you had threads on both ends. Think about cutting the arm to size and then get it threaded at your plumbing store.

[image]

Comment: Threading the pipe sounds great, but the OP did mention that it's _plastic_ pipe. Maybe it can be threaded aftermarket, but it may well be too thin for that. 'tis a good idea if possible...

Comment: @FreeMan  I was referring to threading the shower arm after cutting it to size.

Comment: Oh. Yeah. I guess that makes more sense. _Goes to get moar coffee_

Comment: @FreeMan  I'm on my second cup.